# Why getting “error TS1005: 'from' expected” when generating a service in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and trying to build a small logging app - just to get in. For the logs I wanna created a service and did it with ng g s services/log. Finally I added it to the app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LogFormComponent } from './components/log-form/log-form.component';
import { LogsComponent } from './components/logs/logs.component';
import { LogService } from './services/log.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LogFormComponent,
    LogsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [LogService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But now, after compiling, I get the following error:

ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:11:1 - error TS1005: 'from' expected.

[compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74HQE.png)

Unfortunately I couldn't find any solution for this on stackoverflow or anywhere else so far and really don't know, why the compiler expects a  'from' in line 11.

I'm using Angular/CLI 8.3.24

I'd be really thankful if anybody could help me to solve this!

Kind Regards,

Michael

Comment: in the root of your project, what does `tsc --version` output?

Comment: It outputs Version 3.7.5

Comment: hmm, what about `which tsc` and it should output the path to the typescript compiler that is being used.

Comment: The path is /c/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/npm/tsc...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem by removing the service from `providers: []` in `app.module.ts`.

In newer Angular the service is going to be registered with the root injector

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

by default. Thanks for watching on it...))